# When $\pi(x) \leqslant 0.4x +1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, prime-numbers

It is claimed [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1401.4368) (Lemma 2.2) that $\pi(x) \leqslant 0.4x +1$ when $x\geqslant 7.5$. Is it really so? I am very confused about the proof.

Here $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes that do not exceed $x$.

Comment: $x=7$ is the only exception to $\pi(x)\leqslant0.4~x+1$

Comment: Would you please elaborate on why is it so?

Comment: @Lucian The argument of $\pi$ need not be an integer, it's wrong for $7 \leqslant x < 7.5$.

Comment: @Z.F.:  why what is so?  Can you compute both sides for $x=3,5,7,11$ and see if the inequality is satisfied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is so.  First we demonstrate it by calculation at $x=7.5, \pi(7.5)=4$ because of the primes $2,3,5,7$ and $0.4 \cdot 7.5+1=4$  Then we note that if it fails, it can only fail at $x$ a prime because that is when the left side increases.  It succeeds at $x=11$, where $\pi(11)=5 \le 0.4\cdot 11 +1=5.4$ and at $13$.  Finally we note that if we increase $x$ by $6$, the left side increases by at most $2$ because there can be only two primes in the range-three of the numbers are even and one is odd and divisible by $3$.  The right side increases by $0.4 \cdot 6=2.4$, so the difference keeps increasing.

Answer (score 1):

$\pi(x)\sim x/\log x$, so $\pi(x)\le\varepsilon x$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $x$ depending on $\varepsilon.$ The proof in the paper depends on checking the range [7.5, 17) manually and using induction on larger numbers. (Note that a prime $p>3$ must be $\pm1\pmod6$ and so only at most two out of every six numbers can be prime in this range.)